# Which wireless controller is more compatible with Macs: Xbox 360 or PS3?

Tags: macos, games

I want to buy a gaming controller to play games like GTA3 from the App Store. Which controller will be most compatible with Mac OS X and games on Macs?

Especially it will be useful to know if you have any experience with setting up either PS3 or Xbox controller for Mac.

**Update:** I'm especially interested in correct functioning of the analog controls (joysticks).

Answer (score 8):

Having tried both the Xbox controller and the PS3 controller on my Mac I can say: the PS3 controller is somewhat easier to get working with the Mac. It communicates via BlueTooth and pairing it is mostly painless. It's also wireless without requiring any other devices to be purchased. You can get the PS3 controller drivers [from here](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Ps3Controller).

The Xbox controller requires an [additional USB dongle](http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Hardware/Controllers/Pages/XboxWirelessGamingReceiverforWindows.aspx/) from Microsoft to get working if you want to use a wireless controller. Otherwise, you'll have to stick to using it as a wired controller. You can get the Xbox 360 controller drivers [from here](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller) or here is [an alternative driver](http://xhd.sourceforge.net/).

I thought the drivers for the PS3 controller were a little more stable and that the stick response was snappier than the 360 controller. But I much prefer the 360 controllers layout, weight and overall tactile feel. Personal preference there really.

Answer (score 0):

I only have the Xbox controller, I set it up using [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIu5c9W2DY8) but to be honest I didn't like it, something doesn't feel right about using a controller and playing games on my Mac.

But they are both compatible, you just need the correct accessories to connect them. Decide by choosing which one you prefer.

If you do not mind it not being Xbox or PS3 you can get plenty of controllers for the Mac simply by Googling "Mac games controllers"

Answer (score 0):

A little app called **Joystick Mapper** can allow you to use any compatible controller with any game—whether it supports your gamepad/joystick or not.

All you need is a connected joystick or gamepad to get started.

[image]

From there, you can create a new joystick and select it in the app's settings. Once you've done that, you simply bind buttons on your device to keyboard strokes and mouse actions to control whatever game you want in the way you want to control it.

It is available from the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/joystick-mapper/id528183797?mt=12) for $4.99.